# Wallet Creation Height

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Upon creating a wallet in the GUI. At what point does the wallet.cpp scan the BC to get a creation height?. My wallet creation height seems to be different completely to the actual blockchain height.

Answer (score 0):

It is normally the current blockchain height. Do you see a different behavior? How do you tell it's not the blockchain height from wallet creation time?

Comment: Gettings a creation height of 25000+/- which is way below the actual height.. Tried scanning the the wallet.cpp & settings.qml to try source the issue however i don't see how it gets to that number.

Comment: Was the daemon synced when you created the wallet?

Comment: no it hadden't sync'd, got any idea how its getting 25000 as a block height?

Comment: I was thinking the daemon may have seen 25000 blocks...